# I want render HTML (from react) code in react native using react-native-render-html package everything works fine but audio and video not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-video, react-native-render-html

Hi I'm trying to render html code which include video and audio tags everything rendering perfectly but audio and video tag not rendering.
Here my code is

```
const HtmlContentCoponent = ({sourceData}) => {
const source = {
html: `<div class=\"se-component \" contenteditable=\"false\"><h1>hiii</h1><figure> 
<audio controls=\"true\" origin-size=\",\" src=\"https://nf1f8200- 
a.akamaihd.net/downloads/ringtones/files/mp3/tumse-mohabbat-hai-slowed-reverb-hindi- 
song-59437.mp3\" data-index=\"0\" data-file-name=\"tumse-mohabbat-hai-slowed-reverb- 
hindi-song-59437.mp3\" data-file-size=\"0\" class=\"active\" style=\"\"></audio> 
</figure></div>`
};

 return (
 <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}>
  <RenderHtml
    source={source}
    tagsStyles={tagsStyles}
  />
 </View>
);
};

export default HtmlContentCoponent;
```

and this is the page
[image]

just see in source h1 tag and audio both are available but h1 only rendering.